# What is covariance of two different wiener processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

I wonder what is covariance of two different wiener processes, say $W_t$ and $V_t$:

$$Cov(W_t,V_t) = \text{ }?$$

If it was one process we could use the property that $\Delta = W_t - W_s \text{~} N(0, t-s)$ to get that

$$Cov(W_t,W_s) = Cov( W_s + (W_t - W_s) ,W_s) = s, \text{    } s \leq t$$

However, I don't know, whether it's possible to do it in the same way. Intuitively, the  $Cov(W_t,V_t)$ is zero.

Comment: If I set V=-W I don’t think it’s zero

Comment: Thank you for noting. Then I need to find how to evaluate that $Cov$.

Comment: That depends on how your two processes are related, which you haven't said. If they are independent, the covariance is zero; at the other extreme point, if V=W or V=-W, the covariance is clearly non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it depends on the task. Usually, it is stated in the problem set whether the the processes are independent.
Roughly, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $ \Bbb Corr(X,Y) = 0$ or
$$\Bbb Corr(X,Y) = \frac{ \Bbb Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y} \implies \Bbb Cov(X,Y) = 0$$
If nothing about independence is said, we cannot say the $\Bbb Cov$ is zero.